# You have an error in your SQL syntax in PDO

Tags: mysql, pdo

I am trying to fix my sql problem for 3 hours and I cant find the little thing the destroy my code.

The error :

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order, image, category_id) VALUES('test', 'test', '<p>test' at line 1

The query: All the variables they are post fields that sended.

```
try {
    $statement = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO `info_pages` (name, title, text, img_credits, meta_title, meta_keywords, order, image, category_id) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $statement->execute(array($main_title, $side_title, $content, $img_credits, $meta_title, $meta_keywords, $order, $image, $category_id));
    //echo $BNL->msg("הדף <b>{$main_title}</b> נוצר בהצלה, הנך מועבר...", true);
    //echo $BNL->MoveTo($url."index.php?page=info_pages",1);
    if (!$statement->execute()) {
        print_r($statement->errorInfo());
    }
} catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $BNL->msg("<b>שגיאה</b>, צרו קשר עם המנהל");
}
```

Comment: `order` is a reserved word, needs quoting.

Answer (score 0):

grave is more commonly referred to as a "backtick", which MySQL uses to escape MySQL reserved words.

Already @Mat said his comment that you used reserve word in your statement that why its thrown error and that is "order",so if you use this type reserve word you have write your query below way.

```
("INSERT INTO `info_pages`
        (`name`,
         `title`,
         `text`,
         `img_credits`,
         `meta_title`,
         `meta_keywords`,
         `order`,
         `image`,
         `category_id`)
          VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
```

Though i used for every column but not needed that you can use it for only "order" column

Comment: would you mind to elaborate on why this query should work? for SO reference and for who will come later to seek for the same issue

Comment: btw you don't need to escape all the column names with backticks but just those that are reserved words

Comment: Thanks @LelioFaieta i going to describe about reserve words order